# Meteorite flash above Congress building around 35:02 mark in Sleepy Hollow

Tags: sleepy-hollow-tv

In Sleepy Hollow S3 E1, somewhere around 35:02 mark, there is a shot with Congress  in the distance

Just before Ichabod and Jenny are about to walk into the frame, there is a flash of light above Congress in the sky.

Is that an actual meteor or a digitally added meteor for some reason?

[image]

Comment: negatory on that for two reasons: Visually it was way too fast moving and getting brighter to have been a plane, movie based reason, no planes can fly over Washington DC ( I learned that from one of the movies with skyjumpers, not sure which one)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a meteor.....meteors don't have curved trajectories..

[image]

One possible explanation is that this is an aircraft circling to land at Washington Dulles airport but the apparent speed of the object would seem to indicate this is not the case.

On closer examination though...it's **much** more likely that this is a white bird (similar to the one flying in the lower part of the screen) that is catching the sun. It does seem, if you look closely, that there is some flapping of wings...

Comment: Quite a observation. Yes looks like bird

Comment: What seems to be flapping of the wings also looks like meteor burning up, sometimes meteors burn up in number of flashes. Also the problem with it being a bird is that it is in quite distance, and if it too fast moving to be a plane then certainly it cant be a bird.

Comment: Meteors dont *curve*. The bird isn't in the distance....it's much closer and smaller.